# Is it possible to create animated dynamic emissive dynamic footprints coming from a character animation?

Tags: animation, texturing, modifiers, animation-nodes, effects

I'd like to create an effect like the below for an animated sequence. I want the character to leave behind glowing footprints on the surface of the stairs they're walking on.

Would something like this be possible? I've been looking into wet maps but also looking for a way to do it without affecting the geometry of surface the character is walking on. Like maybe layering an emissive texture under the original? ideally they would appear as the character steps on them then slowly disappear.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

[image: REFERENCE IMAGE]

Comment: Have you looked into Physics > Dynamic Paint?

Comment: I have not. I will have a look into this today, thank you :)